# Right syntax of lambda javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, lambda

I´m trying to set some values within a object using forEach lambda:

```
 var row = {title: "", attribute:"", width: ""};
 list.forEach( list =>
                 row.title = list.label |
                 row.attribute = list.label |
                 row.width = "300px"    
              );
```

Works fine only with a statement `row.title = list.label` when I add the rest of parameters does not work fine.

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Note that the term "lambda" is virtually never used in JavaScript. A "lambda" is called "anonymous function" in JS.

Comment: I think it is called _arrow function_.

Comment: Have you tried `{}`? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
 var row = {title: "", attribute:"", width: ""};
 list.forEach( list => {
                 row.title = list.label;
                 row.attribute = list.label;
                 row.width = "300px"    
              });
```

Notice the curly braces.

Answer (score 7):

You need curly brackets, as the part after the `=>` is a function body:

```
 var row = {title: "", attribute:"", width: ""};
 list.forEach( list => {
   row.title = list.label;
   row.attribute = list.label;
   row.width = "300px";
 });
```

(Be advised that if this is the code you are actually running, the values in `row` will be set to the values of the last entry in list.)

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap non-returning statements in arrow function with curly brackets:

```js
var list = [
  { label: 'one'   },
  { label: 'two'   },
  { label: 'three' }
];

var row = {title: "", attribute:"", width: ""};

list.forEach(list => {
  row.title = list.label;
  row.attribute = list.label;
  row.width = "300px";
  console.log('Row is', row);
  console.log();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands `row` will hold the data in each of your loops of .forEach, so you will only be getting the data of the last element that was processed. You want to make a new object to store the data "for each" of these loops, and then have a populated array.

```
var Row = (title, attribute, width) => {
  this.title = title;
  this.attribute = attribute;
  this.width = width;
};

var rows = [];
list.forEach( item => { 
  rows.push(new Row(list.label, list.label, "300px"));
});
```

Alternatively, the `map` function could do what you want in less code.

```
var rows = list.map( ( item ) => {
  return new Row(item.label, item.label, "300px");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure your code demonstrates your point: note that you have a variable named `item` and you don't use it (in the first snippet)